# saving with NSMutableData and NSKeyedArchiver a UIObject

Tags: ios, xcode

I am building an app using storyboard. I have a view controller where the user has a set of tools (UILabels, images...), and can add these items by clicking on a specific button. When I exit the view controller or closes the app though all the data is lost. so I tried setting up a save button in this way:

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad {


[super viewDidLoad];

UIBarButtonItem *cameraButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                 initWithTitle:@"Camera"
                                 style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                 target:self
                                 action:@selector(useCamera:)];

UIBarButtonItem *cameraRollButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                     initWithTitle:@"Camera Roll"
                                     style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                     target:self
                                     action:@selector(useCameraRoll:)];
NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: cameraButton,
                  cameraRollButton, nil];
[toolbar setItems:items animated:NO];

mouseMoved = 0;

   array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
array2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
  array3 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSFileManager *filemgr; NSString *docsDir; NSArray *dirPaths;
    filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    // Get the documents directory
    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                                   NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    // Build the path to the data file
    dataFilePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir
                                                      stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"data.archive"]];
    // Check if the file already exists
    if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: dataFilePath]) {

        dataArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile: dataFilePath];
        array = [dataArray objectAtIndex:0]; array2 = [dataArray objectAtIndex:1]; array3 = [dataArray objectAtIndex:2];


}}


-(void)saveData{

    NSMutableArray *contactArray;
    contactArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; [contactArray addObjectsFromArray:array]; [contactArray addObjectsFromArray:array2]; [contactArray addObjectsFromArray:array3]; [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:
                                                                                                                                                     contactArray toFile:dataFilePath];
[self.view addSubview: image1];
        [self.view addSubview: text1];
    [self.view addSubview: label1];

}
```

when I press the buttons the you can see that the codes are triggers (NSLog), but nothing happens. in the above example when I click save, the UILabel the user has created (alloc), should be saved, and when the app is open again, the button unarchive should place the label exactly how it is, and in the same position. I have to do tho even for the UIImageViews, and UITextFields.

Since I added all the user created labels... in an array, I want to save the whole objects in the array. The above code does not work though. I can't understand why.this is how I created the array and the object (in .h I added NSMutableArray *array;)

```
CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake( 400, 100, 100, 30);

label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: labelFrame];
[label1 setText: @"Untitled"];
[label1 setTextColor: [UIColor orangeColor]];
[self.view addSubview:label1];
label1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
     UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchGesture = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scalePiece:)];

     [label1 addGestureRecognizer:pinchGesture];

if (array == nil) array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[array addObject:label1];
```

thanks in advance for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

Try logging your loaded objects and you should see that they are actually loaded. You don't see them of course since you don't add them to the view hierarchy. Try adding those lines after you get your objects from the dictionary:

```
[self.view addSubview: label1];
[self.view addSubview: text1];
[self.view addSubview: image1];
```

This might work, but it is not a good idea though. You really should read some introductory material to object-oriented programming and the Model/View/Controller (MVC) design pattern.

Comment: Now it works, but only for the last created object, but I want all the objects is the array to be left. I tried looking up MVC but its only a model. Is it a more efficient way of doing it? can you save the hole view controller?